# How to match a ListBuffer's items to an Array's item in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, if-statement

So I have a use case where I have a ListBuffer of Strings [let's call it 'A'], and an array of Strings (or if it's easier let's take it as another ListBuffer) [let's call it 'B']. There are no duplicate of items in either A or B

Now I want to do this:

```
if (A.isEmpty){
     // do something
}
else if (every item of 'A' must be present in 'B'){
     // do something else
}
else{
     // do something different
}
```

This should take care of edge cases like:

- B is empty ['else if' check should fail]
- len(A) < len(B), but items of A are there in B ['else if' check should pass]
- others...

How should I write the **else if** block in this case?

Comment: `else if (a.diff(b).isEmpty) ...`

Comment: @jwvh Does this work if `A` is shorter than `B` or the elements are in different orders?

Comment: @Tim; Yes it does. The only situation where you might get a bad result is if `a` has a duplicate element not reflected in the `b` collection, but the OP has ruled that out.

Comment: Cool :) I would have assumed that `diff` was the disjunction of two sets, so I find it odd that `a diff b` is not the same as `b diff a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slow version

```
A.forall(B.contains)
```

Faster version

```
val bSet = B.to(Set)
A.forall(bSet.contains)
```

And a version from @jwvh that is probably somewhere in the middle

```
a.diff(b).isEmpty
```